# Can I use overdue to identify a task finished behind schedule?

Tags: word-request

I'm translating some labels and messages of a web system to English. In the context of learning, there are activities that must be finished on a specific date, like in a classroom with teachers and students. I want to know the word teachers usually use to define a task that is finished behind schedule, is it ok to use **"overdue"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word that is usually used in a school setting is "**late**." "Overdue" implies something more along the lines of a library book, not a school assignment.

Usage:

> If you turn assignments in late, you lose ten percent of your grade for each day it is late.
>
> I finished the essay last night, but since I turned it in after midnight, it was late.

Definition:

> Late: occurring, coming, or being after the usual or proper time
>
> [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/late)